# Moving a unordered_map of unique_ptr into another

Tags: c++, c++11, move, unordered-map, unique-ptr

I'm trying to move a unordered_map of unique_ptr's into another map, but getting the compile error below.

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> aMap;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> bMap;

    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int);
    *ptr = 10;
    aMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::move(ptr)));

    std::move(aMap.begin(), aMap.end(), bMap.end());


    return 0;
}


1>------ Build started: Project: Testing, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 08.07.2012 23:54:16.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\Testing.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>d:\progs\visual studio 2010\vc\include\utility(260): error C2166: l-value specifies const object
1>          d:\progs\visual studio 2010\vc\include\utility(259) : while compiling     class template member function 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::operator =(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const int,
1>              _Ty2=std::unique_ptr<int>
1>          ]
1>          d:\coding\testing\main.cpp(12) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const int,
1>              _Ty2=std::unique_ptr<int>
1>          ]
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.64
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow was ever even tarted, let alone re-tarted

Comment: I guess I'm the retard now :)

Comment: I believe part of the issue is that the combination of insert and make_pair is trying to call the copy constructor of the unique ptr, which doesn't exist. If you change unique_ptr to shared_ptr it will compile up to your std::move(aMap.begin()... That being said, you have the right idea with the std::move on the arguement of make_pair, as if you do that standalone it does work, but fails and tries to call the copy constructor on aMap.insert.

Comment: Yes, but I'll rather use unique_ptr though as I want to have explicit ownership..

Comment: See comments below, was an issue with g++ 4.4.5, unique_ptr is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue that you can't add elements to a map or set by copying to the end.  A more simple example that illustrate this is

```
std::set<int> aSet;
std::set<int> bSet;
aSet.insert(0);

std::move(aSet.begin(), aSet.end(), bSet.end());
```

to get around this, you need an insert_iterator, so

```
std::move(aSet.begin(), aSet.end(), inserter(bSet, bSet.begin()));
```

or

```
std::move(aMap.begin(), aMap.end(), inserter(bMap, bMap.begin()));
```

Internally, the insert iterator will attempt to call 'insert' in the passed in container, so rather than trying to do '*(bMap.end()) = *(aMap.begin())', it will call 'bMap.insert(pos, *(aMap.begin()))', though pos is not extremely important for this situation.

Comment: This solution when applied to the problem works if you take into account the issue with insert calling the copy constructor, which means you would have to use shared_ptr's, or find a different solution.

Comment: @trickfire
Is insert required to call the copy constructor though? I honestly haven't delved into the issue, but I would assume stl implementations might include a definition for set<T>::insert(T && rval). Even if you just had a pass-by-value version set<T>::insert(T ppv) you could still prevent the copy; when 'insert' is called, it is passed a 'T &&' (because it's called by std::move). When it encounters set<T>::insert(T ppv), it creates T ppv, and passes as argument the rvalue from std::move, so T's move constructor is invoked. Same with when the value is put in place into the set.

Comment: I haven't looked too much into the rvalue references myself, this was simply from testing with unique_ptr and shared_ptr on the OP's question. I would think that it would work too myself, I'm not quite sure why insert is calling the copy constructor, but that's what I am seeing in the compiler dump. (g++ 4.4.5, so it's a bit older; haven't tested it on a newer compiler).

Comment: @Trickfire How do you see that in g++? 4.4.5 may not have had the support for x11 features that 4.7 does.

Comment: Using g++ -std=c++0x I get:  /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/unique_ptr.h: In copy constructor âstd::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >::pair(const std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > >&)â: And a bunch more.

Comment: Just confirming that is an issue with g++ 4.4.5. I just tested that code out with VS2010 and it does work (without changing to a shared_ptr) with your answer. I really need to manually update it, but g++ 4.4.5 is the highest version in the Debian repo's it's running on.